# Drawing a basket in Tikz 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

For some mathematics project I'm trying to draw a basket as sketched in the picture below,

[image: Sketch of what I want to get (minus some basic shading)]

I've gotten some of the lines of the basket in, see picture below after the MWE, however I'm still struggeling to get some of the shading right, mainly on the handle. I was looking for some shading of part of a sphere, but have thusfar not found anything. Would anyone be able to help out.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[]{calc}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{90}{90}{0}
        \tdplotdrawarc[fill = gray, tdplot_rotated_coords]{(O)}{1}{-90}{90}{}{}
        \tdplotdrawarc[fill = lightgray, tdplot_main_coords]{(O)}{1}{0}{360}{}{}        
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{-160}{90}{180}
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,.2)}{1}{-89.5}{90.5}{}{} 
        \tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,-.2)}{1}{-89.5}{90.5}{}{}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: What the code produces]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Another approach, using `isometric view` option from `perspective` Ti*k*Z library and also `3d` library. I made the handle cylindrical, there is hardly any difference and it's easier this way.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,rotate around z=180,line cap=round,line join=round]
\def\w{0.15}                      % handle width
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{asin(\w)}      % handle angle 
\pgfmathsetmacro\r{sqrt(1-\w*\w)} % handle radius
\draw[fill=gray!30] (-45:1) arc (-45:135:1) arc (0:-180:1cm);
\draw[bottom color=gray,top color=gray!40] (0,0) circle (1);
\path[canvas is yz plane at x=-\w] (\r,0) arc (0:135:\r) coordinate (T); % tangent point
% inner handle
\draw[bottom color=gray!40] (270-\a:1) arc (270-\a:270+\a:1) 
    {[canvas is yz plane at x=\w] arc (180:135:\r) -- (T) arc (135:180:\r)};
% outer handle
\draw[fill=gray!30] (90+\a:1) arc (90+\a:90-\a:1)
    {[canvas is yz plane at x=\w] (\r,0) arc (0:135:\r) -- (T)  arc (135:0:\r)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thank you very much!

Comment: @MatthewLou, You're welcome :D

Comment: You *handle*d that beautifully.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, thanks!!! XD

Answer (score 4):

It is rather straightforward to compute the angle of visibility, thus allowing for arbitrary view angles.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{0}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,
        declare function={tcrit(\x)=atan2(cos(\x)*sin(\tdplotmaintheta),cos(\tdplotmaintheta));% limit of visibility
        w=.2;% width of the handle
        }]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myphi}{-30}% view angle
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{asin(w)}% angle computed from the width of the band
        \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\myphi}{00}{0}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tcrit}{tcrit(\myphi)}% critical angle
        \begin{scope}[tdplot_rotated_coords,smooth,variable=\t]
            \draw[top color=black,bottom color=gray!50!black] 
                plot[domain=0:\tcrit] ({sin(\myalpha)},{cos(\myalpha)*cos(\t)},{sin(\t)}) 
                -- plot[domain=\tcrit:0] ({-sin(\myalpha)},{cos(\myalpha)*cos(\t)},{sin(\t)})
                -- plot[domain=-\myalpha:\myalpha-360]  ({sin(\t)},{cos(\t)},0);
            \draw[ball color=gray] 
                plot[domain=90+\myphi:-\myalpha+180] ({sin(\t)},{cos(\t)},0) --
                plot[domain=180:\tcrit] ({sin(\myalpha)},{cos(\myalpha)*cos(\t)},{sin(\t)}) 
                 -- plot[domain=\tcrit:180] ({-sin(\myalpha)},{cos(\myalpha)*cos(\t)},{sin(\t)})
                 -- plot[domain=180+\myalpha:270+\myphi] ({sin(\t)},{cos(\t)},0) 
                 [tdplot_screen_coords] 
                 arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=1];
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use, say, `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myphi}{20}` instead, you get:

[image]